# Rapidoid custom config file is ignored

Tags: rapidoid

I'm very new to Rapidoid and I'm experiencing problem with initial configuration of the application. I'm using Rapidoid 5.5.5 with following Rapidoid modules defined in pom:

- rapidoid-commons
- rapidoid-http-server
- rapidoid-web

Java 11 is used to run the application.

I've prepared a custom *config-develop.yml* file where I've changed value for port to use from default 8080 to 18888 and added some menu items in **gui:** section however when I start application none of my changes were used: generated log does not have any data about accepting/use of parameters from my file and configuration files are the files that are included into **rapidoid-commons** Maven artefact.

Also, the log shows that classpath used is limited to /target/classes folder (I'm using Maven as build tool). So, these are my questions:

1. What are the rules for merging configuration information when multiple config-*.yml files are present in search path?
2. How I can tell Rapidoid to ignore some configuration files?
3. Is it possible to specify explicit name for configuration file as part of initialisation process?

I'm happy to provide additional information if this will help to find an answer to the questions above.

With best regards,
Nick